# Split svg image with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Is it possible to split ready SVG image using JS and e.g. change background color of one part below horizontal line x = 30px?

```
    <svg width="50px" height="50px">
        <image xlink:href="firefox.jpg" height="50px" width="50px">
    </svg>
```

I've created a few smaller image, but I'm looking for better solution, more dynamically.

Thanks for help!